# Angular2 Error trying to diff '[object Object]'

Tags: json, angular, primeng

I wanted to upgrade my app, so the data displayed in css/bootstrap would be changed to Prime NG `DataTable` where I can filter and sort the data. First of all I tried `DataTable` with dummy class + dummy data. It was working fine. But when I tried to integrate this with my app which takes the data from JSON, it crashes with `Error trying to diff '[object Object]'`.

Checking this problem here and on the internet didn't helped, because it only made some speculations like Angular does not check if data inside `DataTable` was changed (I'm not even sure if it's true).

Before the changes in my app, you had to login with correct username and password to display the data behind the logged account. Now when I login, it doesn't work with Prime NG `DataDatble`.

Simplified code:

**Vehicle.Service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class VehicleService {
    private defUrl = 'someURL';

    constructor(private http: Http) { }
    getVehicle(username?: string, password?: string) {
        const url = (!username || !password) ? this.defUrl : 'someURL' + username + '/' + Md5.hashStr(password);
        return this.http.get(url)
            .map(res => res.json());

    }
```

**Vehicle.component.ts**

```
  public vehicles: GeneralVehicle[];

  constructor(private vehicleService: VehicleService, private router: Router) {
    this.vehicleService.getVehicle().subscribe(vehicle => {
      this.vehicles = vehicle;
      this.vehicles = this.vehicleService.parseUser();
    });
  }
```

**Template: vehicle.html**

```
<div *ngIf="vehicles">
    <p-dataTable [value]="vehicles">
        <p-column field="vehicles.vehicle_id" header="ID"></p-column>
        <p-column field="vehicles.dallassettings" header="Name"></p-column>
    </p-dataTable>
</div>
```

Exemplary JSON from url (status occures once, all the "interesting" data is inside the `dallases` array).

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "dallases": [{
        "vehicle_id": 17954,
        "dallassettings": "3",
        "dallasupdated": "False",
        "dallas_list": [{
            "number": 666111222,
            "auth": 3
        }, {
            "number": 666777888,
            "auth": 4
        }, {
            "number": 123454321,
            "auth": 4
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass in html as

```
<div *ngIf="vehicles.dallases">
    <p-dataTable [value]="vehicles.dallases">
        <p-column field="vehicles.dallases.vehicle_id" header="ID"></p-column>
        <p-column field="vehicles.dallases.dallassettings" header="Name"></p-column>
    </p-dataTable>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solutions works if I use `*ngfF="vehicles"` (if I use `vehicles.dallases` it points out a error with undefinfed `dallases`), but the `DataTable` is empty. However, if I intentionally input wrong username and password there is one row with: `No records found`. Is something not right with the service or constructor?

Comment: I found the issue, something's up with saving the username and password. It's not related to this question. Thanks for help!